# C++ ошибка при подключении библиотеки - fatal error: tgbot/tgbot.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include

Всем привет!
Недавно решил разобраться в c++ и переписать телеграмм бота с python на c++. 
Скачал vcpkg - https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/#quick-start-windows
через него установил tgbot - https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp

Поставил начальный код

```
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <tgbot/tgbot.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace TgBot;

void createOneColumnKeyboard(const vector<string>& buttonStrings, ReplyKeyboardMarkup::Ptr& kb)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < buttonStrings.size(); ++i) {
    vector<KeyboardButton::Ptr> row;
    KeyboardButton::Ptr button(new KeyboardButton);
    button->text = buttonStrings[i];
    row.push_back(button);
    kb->keyboard.push_back(row);
  }
}

void createKeyboard(const vector<vector<string>>& buttonLayout, ReplyKeyboardMarkup::Ptr& kb)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < buttonLayout.size(); ++i) {
    vector<KeyboardButton::Ptr> row;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < buttonLayout[i].size(); ++j) {
      KeyboardButton::Ptr button(new KeyboardButton);
      button->text = buttonLayout[i][j];
      row.push_back(button);
    }
    kb->keyboard.push_back(row);
  }
}


int main() {
    string token(getenv("6521141539:AAH7ZiWW5P6HWGAy-nBTI09Sftw1gE_u2vY"));
    printf("Token: %s\n", token.c_str());

    Bot bot(token);

    ReplyKeyboardMarkup::Ptr keyboardOneCol(new ReplyKeyboardMarkup);
    createOneColumnKeyboard({"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"}, keyboardOneCol);

    ReplyKeyboardMarkup::Ptr keyboardWithLayout(new ReplyKeyboardMarkup);
    createKeyboard({
      {"Dog", "Cat", "Mouse"},
      {"Green", "White", "Red"},
      {"On", "Off"},
      {"Back"},
      {"Info", "About", "Map", "Etc"}
    }, keyboardWithLayout);

    bot.getEvents().onCommand("start", [&bot, &keyboardOneCol](Message::Ptr message) {
        bot.getApi().sendMessage(message->chat->id, "/start for one column keyboard\n/layout for a more complex keyboard", false, 0, keyboardOneCol);
    });
    bot.getEvents().onCommand("layout", [&bot, &keyboardWithLayout](Message::Ptr message) {
        bot.getApi().sendMessage(message->chat->id, "/start for one column keyboard\n/layout for a more complex keyboard", false, 0, keyboardWithLayout);
    });
    bot.getEvents().onAnyMessage([&bot](Message::Ptr message) {
        printf("User wrote %s\n", message->text.c_str());
        if (StringTools::startsWith(message->text, "/start") || StringTools::startsWith(message->text, "/layout")) {
            return;
        }
        bot.getApi().sendMessage(message->chat->id, "Your message is: " + message->text);
    });

    signal(SIGINT, [](int s) {
        printf("SIGINT got\n");
        exit(0);
    });

    try {
        printf("Bot username: %s\n", bot.getApi().getMe()->username.c_str());
        bot.getApi().deleteWebhook();

        TgLongPoll longPoll(bot);
        while (true) {
            printf("Long poll started\n");
            longPoll.start();
        }
    } catch (exception& e) {
        printf("error: %s\n", e.what());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Импорт библиотеки не подсвечивается как ошибка, но при запуске выдает ошибку:

```
main.cpp:8:10: fatal error: tgbot/tgbot.h: No such file or directory
    8 | #include <tgbot/tgbot.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Пути:
Vcpkg - D:\vcpkg
Библиотека - D:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\tgbot
w64devkit - D:\w64devkit
Мой проект - D:\Cod\practice\CPP-Telebot\main.cpp

В файле c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Win32",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "D:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include"
      ],

      "defines": [
        "_DEBUG",
        "UNICODE",
        "_UNICODE"
      ],
      
      "compilerPath": "D:/w64devkit/bin/g++.exe",
      "cStandard": "c17",
      "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

В файле launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "d:/Cod/practice/new",
      "program": "d:/Cod/practice/new/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

В файле tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "D:/w64devkit/bin/g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста!
Использую vscode

Comment: Вы описали кучу всего, кроме того где у вас лежит сама библиотека tgbot.h ? По умолчанию, компилятор ищет библиотеку в папке include (там где компилятор). Судя по вашему пути, в include/tgbot/tgbot.h должнен быть файл заголовка и содержимое библиотеки tgbot. А его там нет.

Comment: @FrancNet библиотека - D:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\tgbot
Мне надо переместить папку библиотеки в путь D:\w64devkit\include ?

Comment: @FrancNet 
Возможно я чего-то не понимаю, но я же указал в c_cpp_properties.json includePath - путь, где лежит папка с библиотекой

Comment: Ну вы указали, а он не находит. Библиотеки находятся рядом с компилятором в основном. Там есть папка include, в ней находятся все библиотеки, которые вы подключаете написав #include <имя библиотеки> Вам при компиляции пишет что файл tgbot.h не найден. D:/w64devkit гдето там есть папка include с множеством библиотек. Создайте в include папку tgbot и скопируйте в неё файлы библиотеки tgbot.

Comment: Другой вариант в папке с пректом создать tgbot и в коде изменить #include <tgbot/tgbot.h> на #include "tgbot/tgbot.h" По <> ищет в include а "" где укажете.

Comment: Файл `c_cpp_properties.json` используется для конфигурирования Intellisense, а не для сборки. Настройки сборки указываются в файле `tasks.json`, где необходимо прописывать необходимые аргументы для компилятора. Однако выкаченное посредством vcpkg скорее всего использовать не удастся, так как оно не было собрано тем же компилятором с теми же настройками, что используете вы. Используйте обычную Visual Studio и собирайте библиотеки сами.

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо за информацию! На счёт visual studio пробовал - работает, просто думал что есть способ всё это провернуть в vscode, ибо он мне роднее

Comment: Ну способ-то есть, только с VScode слишком много мороки для использования ее для С++ю